# OLEDB Data into MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, datasource, oledb

I have an OLEDB Data source which (almost) works to get data into excel. However I'm dealing with a lot of data and want to use MS Access to manipulate and report on that.

Given that OLEDB is my only option, and I don't know much about it apart from that, is this possible and if so how? It doesn't seem to be an option on the 'get external data' tab in MS Access despite being in Excel - yet I noticed ODBC is in both?

Comment: So you're saying that the data source from which you are trying to pull data (presumably some sort of database) only has an OLEDB provider and not an ODBC driver?

Comment: @GordThompson Correct. I know, it's a pain, and I'm pressuring the directors to replace it as soon as we can, but in the meantime...

Comment: It's ACT, as discussed in my question that you commented on yesterday

Comment: The [article](https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024246694-How-To-Create-An-ODBC-Connection-For-Use-With-The-ACT-Reader-Utility) I mentioned in my previous comment talks about the [ACT! Reader utility](https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024244694-What-is-the-ACT-Reader-Utility). Have you investigated that option?

Comment: OLEDB connections can be established in VBA. Possibly have to obtain a driver for ACT, if it exists. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-access-to-sql-server-050d88f3-b2d6-4e76-b6f9-f3c556f139 and https://community.act.com/t5/Act-Developer-s-Forum/OLEDB-Connection-String/td-p/72617

Comment: @GordThompson I looked into using ACT reader, but it's not an option for us because the ACT database is stored on a shared server rather than on the local machine.